# Automatically run homebrew tkinter python software upon boot

Tags: bash, scripts

I have an executable script `~/.todo/todorun.sh` that opens a gui (built in python) performing some task when it's run as `/bin/bash ~/.todo/todorun.sh`

I attempted to get this script to run by adding this command to the startup applications (through the GUI accessed in ubuntu), but this did not work.

How can I get this script to run automatically as soon as I log in? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: you have a sub directory in your home directory called `.todo`? If that is correct then in the Startup applications command use `/home/kevin/.todo/todorun.sh` Also make sure the execution bit is set with `chmod a+x /home/kevin/.todo/todorun.sh` and the first line in the file `todorun.sh` is `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Yes, that's correct -- `~/.todo` is a directory containing some scripts. Thanks. I will try using `/home/kevin` instead of `~`. I need to study `man chmod` a little to learn what `a` means.

Comment: Thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix ! That fixed it. The issue was that I tried to specify the directory of the script to the startup applications using `~` instead of `/home/kevin`.

Comment: I've posted an answer. As a new user you may not know you can accept it by clicking grey check mark next to the answer. This takes your question off the sites "to-do" list and lets other people with same problem know the solution. Additionally you gain 2 rep points and I gain 15...

Answer (score 0):

Startup Applications does not recognize `~` and expand it to `/home/kevin` so you need to format the command as:

```
/home/kevin/.todo/todorun.sh
```